# With bootstrap how to keep group of navigation items together

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and have been trying to put together a basic navigation bar. The issue I have is how to keep elements together without making use of a form element.

The search button is floating under the Search input element as shown jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pehjae0c/)

My intended result is to have both input and button juxtaposed as shown below but at the same time keep distance from other menu items:
[image]

What is the bootstrap configuration (or classes) to achieve this effect?

My HTML is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-top:3px">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div style="width:50px; padding-top:4px; padding-bottom:4px">
                <span>Brand</span>
                <!--<img src="content/images/MaxForms_2.png" />-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">My Action <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <ul class="">
                    <li>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search item">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="input-lg">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $root.saveForm, event:{blur: $root.removeStatus}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Submit Form
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: @YuHao why are you changing the tag to twitter-bootstrap? My understanding is that Bootstrap(www.getBootrap.com) and twitter-bootstrap is not the same. As a matter of fact when you choose the bootstrap from list of tags it reads "not to be confused with twitter-bootstrap..."

Comment: Read the tag info again. http://getbootstrap.com/ is about [the Twitter Bootstrap framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_(front-end_framework)). The other tag **bootstrap** is about [Bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you forgot to check this page. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

However, i create new entry in my fiddle for you to follow.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-top:3px;">
<div class="container-fluid">

  <!-- start your brand -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="hide"> <!-- alt icon for mobile here --> </button>
    <div class="navbar-brand site-brand">
      <span>Brand Name</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <!-- start your menu -->

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- start your form -->
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Another Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
</nav>
```

[JSFiddle Version](http://jsfiddle.net/imarkdesigns/pbcLrp7j/1/)
[JSFiddle Version 2](http://jsfiddle.net/imarkdesigns/pbcLrp7j/3/)

Note: I did add class to the logo section where you can apply or override the style you wanted here... Let me know if everything here is clear.

Comment: thank you regarding the Brand class. However, I still have  a problem: I cannot use the <Form> element to group the input and button element because this is to be used inside a SharePoint web part. The second issue is that the Search/Submit block is right against the 'Another Submit' button. We need to deal with the Search/Submit block as a single menu item equidistant from other items.

Comment: I update the JS Fiddle.. please check if that was what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Got it: the input/button block should be defined as:

```
<li>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-form" >
                        <li>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search item">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Final jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pehjae0c/2/)

I'm happy!